# Using greenlock-express with Express in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, lets-encrypt, greenlock

I have an `express` app that was generated using `express-generator` and would like to use `greenlock-express` with it.

However unlike [the example given by `greenlock-express`](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock-express.js#working-example-code) where you have

```
require('greenlock-express').create({ ... }).listen(80, 443);
```

the express app has `.bin/www` which was generated by `express-generator` where we have

```
var app = require('../app');
var http = require('http');

...

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

In this case, how should we use `greenlock-express`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Just Update Your Greenlock Config

For [security reasons](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/22389) it'll probably be better to use the http/http2 (spdy) wrapper included with greenlock express as the server and require the app into greenlock, instead of trying to manage in directly.

```
var greenlock = require('greenlock-express').create({
  ...
, app: require('./app.js')
});

greenlock.listen(80, 443);
```

When you want to run it on localhost, you can still use the server created by express-generator.

## Greenlock [Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTEn93gxY50&list=PLZaEVINf2Bq_lrS-OOzTUJB4q3HxarlXk): Config for Express.js (Screencast)

[image]

Just a few days ago I created a screencast showing exactly how to do this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTEn93gxY50&list=PLZaEVINf2Bq_lrS-OOzTUJB4q3HxarlXk